# Basic integration using substitution method for a sine function

Tags: definite-integrals, substitution

I looked up the information at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) which is providing for the substitution method.May i ask some additional help to get it right for the following specific integral using the substitution method?

if $\,y(t) = sin(ωt+\theta), \,where \,\,T_0=\frac{2π}{ω_ο} $
How do i convert  from $\int_0^{T_0}y(t)\,dt$ to $\int_0^{2π}sin(ωt+\theta)\,d(ωt)$?

I can understand the first practical example wikipedia is providing for the cos(u) integral but i cannot correctly implement it in the above problem. Please, if you answer it be detailed.I do not feel experienced enough with the substitution method.

Comment: it is a simple substitution $s=\omega t$ with s expressed in the final integral as $\omega t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_0^{T_0}y(t)\,dt=\int_0^{T_0}sin(ωt+\theta)\,dt$$

Let

$$s=\omega t \implies ds=d\omega t$$

thus

$$\int_0^{T_0}y(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\omega T_0}sin(s+\theta)\,ds
=\int_0^{2\pi}sin(s+\theta)\,ds
=\int_0^{2\pi}sin(ωt+\theta)\,d(\omega t)
$$

Comment: i do not know that. i thought i should always do: s=ωt+θ, and i could not solve it :/

Comment: you can solve this one $\int_0^{2\pi}sin(s+\theta)\,ds=[-\cos(s+\theta)]_0^{2\pi}$